# What is the best way to build a C++ string using C format strings?

Tags: c++, c++03

I want to add to my company's code a `std::string fmtString(char const * fmt, ...);` function which lets me build C++ strings from C objects in a printf way.  I really liked the readability of C format strings and would like to bring it over instead of the C++ style of using `operator<<` or `operator+`.

1. Is this a bad / inefficient idea?
2. Does this already exist, or is C-style building of C++ strings already easy without a custom method?
3. What's the best way to implement such a method?  It would have to be thread safe.

EDIT: This needs to work without C++11, but I'm still interested in C++11 solutions to the problem!

Comment: i think it's bad idea. "Prefer compile time bugs to run-time bugs". `operator <<` will not crash the same as printf if you don't give it the good parameters

Comment: It's a bad idea if you're using var args. It can be implemented pretty decently (type safe and decent performance) with template metaprogramming though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
template<class...Args>
std::string fmt( string_view, Args&&... )
```

is a C++11 signature for such a function.  This allows run time type safety and controlled failure.

Do **not** use C style VA-args, as that makes any kind of sensible failure impossible (type checking, arg count checking, etc).

Parsing said `string_view` will take time at runtime, but other than that there is no fundamental inefficiency here.  A `constexpr` parser that turns a string of characters into a parsed formatter may be a good idea, possibly a string-literal.

`boost` has many C-style C++ formatters.

You'll want to walk the format string, looking for format commands.  Dump the non-format text as you go along.  At each format command, switch on it and consume one or more `Args` into an error-generating consumer of the type you expect.

An example of a `%d` consumer would be:

```
template<class T> struct simple_printer;

template<> struct simple_printer {
  void operator()( std::string& s, int x ) const {
    // TODOL print x to s
  }
};
template<class X, class... Ts>
std::false_type
simple_print(std::false_type, Ts&&...) { return {}; }

template<class X, class...Args>
std::true_type
simple_print(std::true_type, std::string& out, Args&&... in ) {
  simple_printer<X>{}( out, std::forward<T>(t) );
}
```

then in the parsing code, when you run into `%d`, you do:

```
if (fmt_code == "%d") {
  auto worked = simple_print( std::is_convertible<Arg0, int>{}, out, std::forward<Arg0>(arg0) );
  if (!worked) {
    // report error then
    return;
  }
}
```

after you parse each format command, you recurse on your print function with less arguments and the tail end of the format string.

Handling more complex formatting (like `%.*f`) is naturally trickier.  It could help if you request that "formatting bundle" arguments are grouped in the `Args` somehow.

Answer (score 1):

This breaks type safety, a feature that was one of the major benefits of moving from C to C++ in the first place. If you send the wrong data, you get runtime crashes or unexpected output, rather than nice cosy compilation failures.

Try [Boost.Format](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/libs/format/), which does what you're doing, but better:

> The format library provides a class for formatting arguments according to a format-string, as does printf, but with two major differences :
>
> - format sends the arguments to an internal stream, and so is entirely type-safe and naturally supports all user-defined types.
> - The ellipsis (...) can not be used correctly in the strongly typed context of format, and thus the function call with arbitrary arguments is replaced by successive calls to an *argument feeding* **operator%**

[It's thread-safe if you follow the one-instance-per-thread model](http://lists.boost.org/boost-users/2009/06/49305.php).

You could improve your own approach by swapping the varargs for variadic templates, but why re-invent the wheel?

Answer (score 0):

Not judging if it is a good idea or not, you could use `vsnprintf` to implement your function.

- http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/vfprintf

The return value of this function will help you determine the size of the needed buffer.